# Switching an xmlns attribute

Tags: android, xml-namespaces

I'm creating a launcher app that can switch between the standard home screens and my own custom. I think I've discovered where I need to switch the reference file for the launcher, but I don't know how to do it.

The line of code is:

```
xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.launcher"
```

which I want to switch to my own file, but I don't know how to do it, as it would have to be in the java file created, in the CheckBoxPreference onClick method.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you misunderstood the role of `xmlns:launcher="..."`.

1. This is XML namespace, it does not directly influence any dynamic behavior.
2. This is static value that is embedded into application's `.apk` as part of resource (the .xml file that has this line). Strictly speaking, it cannot be changed after application is compiled.

So, basically, you can't change the value of `xmlns:launcher`, and even if you could, it wouldn't help you.

Comment: Just found something else- would I be able to change a line like this:    <include android:id="@+id/cell1" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />

Comment: Nope, all xmls are static. They are used to inflate the actual dynamic layout. You should read more about layouts and inflating (`LayoutInfalter`). Try doing some simple android apps using layouts and you'll understand how they work much better.